# Can a plant that has lost all leaves be rejuvinated?

Tags: plant-health, basil

I have a Tulasi (Holy Basil) plant that was lush with green leaves a few months back.

The leaves slowly started to fall off and now only the dry branches were remaining and there are no leaves.

I cut the dry branches but the main stem and some of the major stems are still strong and somewhat moist.

Is there a chance that it can be rejuvinated? If so, how?

Comment: Is the plant in a pot or in the ground? Have you ever fertilized it?